# When referencing DOM declare lib.d.ts in typescript file gives error exited with code 1

Tags: dom, declaration, typescript

When I reference the declare file for the DOM as below in a typescript file

```
///<reference path='.\node_modules\typescript\bin\lib.d.ts' />
```

the typescript compiler tsc throws an error as below:

> The command ... exited with code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reference lib.d.ts - it is automatically included by the TypeScript compiler.

Remove that reference and you should be back to normal - the error is probably a duplicate declaration given that it is essentially referenced twice.